# Sound not working when used by a normal user and the root user

Tags: sound, alsa

I'm not able to play a sound as a normal user and as root user at the same time.
Example:

- I launch Firefox on Youtube to play a video: it works, I can hear the sound of the video.
- While the video is playing, I launch my audio player as root (sudo) and I get the following error:

> AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device
> 'default': Device or resource busy

I'm able to reproduce this error with different applications. Is there a solution to this problem ? Thank you.

Comment: If you launch your audio player as the same normal user, does it work properly?

Comment: Yes, in this case, it works properly.

Comment: Why exactly are you running an audio player as root?

Comment: It is just an example and it happens with all audio applications. In reality, I'm developing a game (with audio) and a GPU profiler force me to run my game as root to profile it.